# Entity Framework Core 1.0 Database Migration at KUDU

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, kudu

I am restricted to connect to Azure SQL Database from my company's network (behind a firewall). Therefore, if I want to run DB migration using Entity Framework Core 1.0, I should be out of the corporate network or send a REST API request to KUDU to invoke a command after deploying an application to Azure App Service.

Based on the wiki document, https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#command, I managed to send a REST API call to KUDU to run EF Core database migration command like:

```
dnx ef database update -c MyDbContext -p MyEfModels
```

I was able to run the same command from my local machine without any issue (using the Azure SQL DB connectionstring, outside the firewall). However, if I run the same command at KUDU it complains:

`` System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.StartupInvoker..ctor(String startupAssemblyName, String environment)
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DbContextOperations..ctor(ILoggerProvider loggerProvider, String assemblyName, String startupAssemblyName, String environment)
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<.ctor>b__2()
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ListContexts>b__0()
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program.Executor.Execute(Action action)
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. ``

Even I can't run the following command either:

```
dnx ef dbcontext list
```

It seems that some assemblies are missing to load but I'm not sure how I can debug it to get more details from the `LoaderExceptions` property of `ReflectionTypeLoadException`. Can anyone help me out, please?

I'm using `Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1-final` and `ASP.NET Core 1.0.0-rc1-update1`.

Comment: when you ran command ````dnx ef database update -c MyDbContext -p MyEfModels````, do you run under the context of your application?  if so maybe try to compare the binary with your local copy. make sure you had uploaded all the binary

Comment: @XiaominWu Thanks for your answer. This is an ASP.NET Core app so there's no binary required but NuGet package libraries outside the codebase.